# Quick search of command options in bash

Tags: bash, manpage

I found myself in a situation where I constantly look for parameters of a command in bash. For instance, `find -type f -name '*py' -print0`. In order to find all of those I need to go through man,info, or --help option which is laborious and time consuming. Is there any way to make this search instant. Ideally, I would love to see something like: `find -type --help` stating help on type option of find.

Comment: It would be useful, but I don't think it is possible. Some programs indeed integrate such feature within themselves, such as by "program --help type" to ask help on the "-type" parameter. However maybe it is possible to construct some arcane shell script which would excavate this info from the man pages.

Comment: I don't know about bash, but zsh is fairly easy to write plugins for, so you may have more luck with that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your man pages open in `less` you can use `/` to search over it.

`man find`

<kbd>/</kbd>`-type`

<kbd>n</kbd>, for next search

<kbd>N</kbd> for previous search

Comment: Very nice. Though not as powerful as a direct search.

Comment: One way to improve it is to precede the query with double space as in `/  -OPTION` - that way you'll effectively end up right at the definition in most cases, skipping parts where `-OPTION` might be used within a sentence.
This is actually something I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I have in my .bashrc

```
# man search
mans()
{
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "I need 2 args.  a man page and a search phrase."
        exit 1
    else
        man -Pless "$1" | grep -C10 --group-separator="==============================" -- "$2"
    fi
}
```

`mans find type` searches the man page for all occurrences of the phrase "type."

Or:
`mans find -type` (with the dash) if you know the exact option you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
function mangrep { man -P less\ -p\ \""${1}"\" ${2}; }
```

to your `.bashrc`. Then `mangrep pattern page` will open the manpage with `less` and directly search for pattern, as in [Blaz Balons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509988/2402684). So

```
mangrep " -print" find
```

gives you the right spot for the `-print` option of `find`. And you can still use `n/N` for forward and backward searching as well as all other features of less.